Process Radium Token Swap in Python
Im a newly on Solana and feel as if my mind is bending xD. Im trying to process a transaction with a function where Ive swapped xxx amount of a token for yyy amount of solana and vice versa to work out the profit that I have made.
here is my current function:
async def calculate_token_changes(pre_token_balances, post_token_balances):
    # Define Solana mint address for comparison
    SOL_MINT = "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112"

    # Initialize dictionaries to hold pre and post balances by mint address
    pre_balances = {bal.mint: float(bal.ui_token_amount.amount) / (10 ** bal.ui_token_amount.decimals) for bal in pre_token_balances}
    post_balances = {bal.mint: float(bal.ui_token_amount.amount) / (10 ** bal.ui_token_amount.decimals) for bal in post_token_balances}

    # Initialize variables to track SOL and token changes
    sol_change = 0
    token_changes = []

    # Calculate change for Solana
    if SOL_MINT in pre_balances or SOL_MINT in post_balances:
        pre_sol_balance = pre_balances.get(SOL_MINT, 0)
        post_sol_balance = post_balances.get(SOL_MINT, 0)
        sol_change = post_sol_balance - pre_sol_balance

    # Calculate changes for other tokens
    all_mints = set(pre_balances.keys()).union(post_balances.keys())
    for mint in all_mints:
        if mint != SOL_MINT:  # Skip Solana
            pre_balance = pre_balances.get(mint, 0)
            post_balance = post_balances.get(mint, 0)
            token_change = post_balance - pre_balance
            if token_change != 0:  # Include only if there's a change
                token_changes.append((mint, token_change))

    return sol_change, token_changes

Whats happening is if I print out what we return I get this:
(0, [(Pubkey(
    HJxYka8JXP6u5cHjE6u7TUMNCXRtV4CoMXXLv4zBXJp,
), -1589391.4204469998)])

The token is correct however the value of solana is wrong - 0 isn't right. I should get 0.397084678 since thats how much I sold it for. Please could someone point me in the right direction - would be very appreciated :)
Here are the pre - token balances im passing the function. These are from get-transaction():
[UiTransactionTokenBalance(
    UiTransactionTokenBalance {
        account_index: 5,
        mint: "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
        ui_token_amount: UiTokenAmount {
            ui_amount: Some(
                65.101542422,
            ),
            decimals: 9,
            amount: "65101542422",
            ui_amount_string: "65.101542422",
        },
        owner: Some(
            "5Q544fKrFoe6tsEbD7S8EmxGTJYAKtTVhAW5Q5pge4j1",
        ),
        program_id: Some(
            "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
        ),
    },
), UiTransactionTokenBalance(
    UiTransactionTokenBalance {
        account_index: 6,
        mint: "HJxYka8JXP6u5cHjE6u7TUMNCXRtV4CoMXXLv4zBXJp",
        ui_token_amount: UiTokenAmount {
            ui_amount: Some(
                258341894.540918,
            ),
            decimals: 6,
            amount: "258341894540918",
            ui_amount_string: "258341894.540918",
        },
        owner: Some(
            "5Q544fKrFoe6tsEbD7S8EmxGTJYAKtTVhAW5Q5pge4j1",
        ),
        program_id: Some(
            "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
        ),
    },
), UiTransactionTokenBalance(
    UiTransactionTokenBalance {
        account_index: 11,
        mint: "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
        ui_token_amount: UiTokenAmount {
            ui_amount: None,
            decimals: 9,
            amount: "0",
            ui_amount_string: "0",
        },
        owner: Some(
            "ESmrKx6Cau5JqbJWsvm7zpVrSraDLqnG9fCsJejfo3zh",
        ),
        program_id: Some(
            "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
        ),
    },
), UiTransactionTokenBalance(
    UiTransactionTokenBalance {
        account_index: 12,
        mint: "HJxYka8JXP6u5cHjE6u7TUMNCXRtV4CoMXXLv4zBXJp",
        ui_token_amount: UiTokenAmount {
            ui_amount: None,
            decimals: 6,
            amount: "0",
            ui_amount_string: "0",
        },
        owner: Some(
            "ESmrKx6Cau5JqbJWsvm7zpVrSraDLqnG9fCsJejfo3zh",
        ),
        program_id: Some(
            "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
        ),
    },
), UiTransactionTokenBalance(
    UiTransactionTokenBalance {
        account_index: 13,
        mint: "HJxYka8JXP6u5cHjE6u7TUMNCXRtV4CoMXXLv4zBXJp",
        ui_token_amount: UiTokenAmount {
            ui_amount: Some(
                2256689.281827,
            ),
            decimals: 6,
            amount: "2256689281827",
            ui_amount_string: "2256689.281827",
        },
        owner: Some(
            "DfNtwErfanRRx2MopiDJS9bmpC7YQnzrT87JyhCLb6Nv",
        ),
        program_id: Some(
            "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
        ),
    },
)] }}

Here are post-token balances:
[UiTransactionTokenBalance(
    UiTransactionTokenBalance {
        account_index: 5,
        mint: "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
        ui_token_amount: UiTokenAmount {
            ui_amount: Some(
                64.704457744,
            ),
            decimals: 9,
            amount: "64704457744",
            ui_amount_string: "64.704457744",
        },
        owner: Some(
            "5Q544fKrFoe6tsEbD7S8EmxGTJYAKtTVhAW5Q5pge4j1",
        ),
        program_id: Some(
            "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
        ),
    },
), UiTransactionTokenBalance(
    UiTransactionTokenBalance {
        account_index: 6,
        mint: "HJxYka8JXP6u5cHjE6u7TUMNCXRtV4CoMXXLv4zBXJp",
        ui_token_amount: UiTokenAmount {
            ui_amount: Some(
                259931285.961365,
            ),
            decimals: 6,
            amount: "259931285961365",
            ui_amount_string: "259931285.961365",
        },
        owner: Some(
            "5Q544fKrFoe6tsEbD7S8EmxGTJYAKtTVhAW5Q5pge4j1",
        ),
        program_id: Some(
            "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
        ),
    },
), UiTransactionTokenBalance(
    UiTransactionTokenBalance {
        account_index: 11,
        mint: "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
        ui_token_amount: UiTokenAmount {
            ui_amount: None,
            decimals: 9,
            amount: "0",
            ui_amount_string: "0",
        },
        owner: Some(
            "ESmrKx6Cau5JqbJWsvm7zpVrSraDLqnG9fCsJejfo3zh",
        ),
        program_id: Some(
            "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
        ),
    },
), UiTransactionTokenBalance(
    UiTransactionTokenBalance {
        account_index: 12,
        mint: "HJxYka8JXP6u5cHjE6u7TUMNCXRtV4CoMXXLv4zBXJp",
        ui_token_amount: UiTokenAmount {
            ui_amount: None,
            decimals: 6,
            amount: "0",
            ui_amount_string: "0",
        },
        owner: Some(
            "ESmrKx6Cau5JqbJWsvm7zpVrSraDLqnG9fCsJejfo3zh",
        ),
        program_id: Some(
            "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
        ),
    },
), UiTransactionTokenBalance(
    UiTransactionTokenBalance {
        account_index: 13,
        mint: "HJxYka8JXP6u5cHjE6u7TUMNCXRtV4CoMXXLv4zBXJp",
        ui_token_amount: UiTokenAmount {
            ui_amount: Some(
                667297.86138,
            ),
            decimals: 6,
            amount: "667297861380",
            ui_amount_string: "667297.86138",
        },
        owner: Some(
            "DfNtwErfanRRx2MopiDJS9bmpC7YQnzrT87JyhCLb6Nv",
        ),
        program_id: Some(
            "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
        ),
    },
)]

